# Jenkins pipeline jiraLinkIssues

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jira, jenkins-pipeline

I try to integrate jenkins and Jira throught pipeline script. I try to create connection between two jira issues

1)my script (tasks INL-6613 and INL-6614 have already created) :
jiraLinkIssues type: 'предыдущая', inwardKey: 'INL-6613', outwardKey: 'INL-6614', site: 'TEST_JIRA'

just like into this documentation (https://jenkinsci.github.io/jira-steps-plugin/steps/issuelink/jira_link_issues/)

2)Also I configured site: 'TEST_JIRA' and it working 100%
3)I can't create link such as into documentation because I haven't use ordinary types :

[image: my types was preconfigured and I just try use one of:]

4)But I have this problem :

{"errorMessages":["Не найдено ни одного типа связи запроса с именем 'предыдущая'."],"errors":{}}

({"errorMessages":["Not found any type of link query named 'предыдущая'."], "errors":{}})

Help me please fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided this problem with using " jiraGetIssueLinkTypes " -pipeline command, so I have seen that 'предыдущая' was just rename of 'link' type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

1. URL encode, change "**предыдушая**" on "**%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F**"
2. use latin symbols instead of cyrillic